# jPlayer javascript event triggers only works on first song

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jplayer

have this in application.js    ... they work, but only for the first song.

first one is on song play, and the second is at 5% (which will eventually be 75%, to count as a song play).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind($.jPlayer.event.play) 
      var band = event.jPlayer.status.media.band;
      var song = event.jPlayer.status.media.song;
      $.get("/playlists/song_display?song=" + song + "&band=" + band);
    });

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
      if (parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute) >= 5 ) {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate) 
        var band = event.jPlayer.status.media.band;
        var song = event.jPlayer.status.media.song;   
        $.get("/playlists/song_counter?song=" + song + "&band=" + band);
      }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

thanks to Ivan, ended up with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
        debugger
      var band = event.jPlayer.status.media.band;
      var song = event.jPlayer.status.media.song;
      $.get("/playlists/song_display?song=" + song + "&band=" + band);

      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
          if (parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute) >= 5 ) {
            debugger
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate) 
            var band = event.jPlayer.status.media.band;
            var song = event.jPlayer.status.media.song;   
            $.get("/playlists/song_counter?song=" + song + "&band=" + band);
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are selecting your elements using element ids

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind(...)
```

This will only apply to the first element matching the id `jquery_jplayer_1`.

If you want to bind events to multiple elements, you could use a class selector instead.

```
$(".jquery_jplayer").bind(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newb.   There is only one element I want to bind to - I need to trigger the jplayer play and timeupdate events, each time they happen, but it only triggers once, on the first song that plays.    somehow it's not resetting?

Comment: The events only trigger once because you unbind the events after they are triggered. Try removing the `unbind` and see what happens.